# Cant output an if statement when using a def function whose values are user inputted

Tags: python-3.x

```
def sum(x, y):
    return x+y
x = input()
y = input()
sum(x, y)
if sum == 15:
    print("It is equal to 15")
else:
    print("It is not equal to 15")
```

So this code here won't output "it isn't equal to 15" even when I put 15 and 0 for the inputs.

I've tried nesting the if statement under the def code block but that didn't work, said it wasn't reachable.

Im new to the return function btw, so id also appreciate it if you could tell me how to better use it in this code. Thank you.

Comment: Covert your `input()` to `int` data type. And don't use a built-in function name as your function name.

Comment: You need to redo an introductory python tutorial, because there are multiple basic things wrong with your code. 1. `input` returns a _string_, not an integer. 2. The _function_ `sum` is never equal to the integer `15`. A function doesn't become equal to its return value. 3. A `sum` finding exists already. Shadowing built-ins with your own definitions is bad form

Comment: Please never answer typo questions. They are meant to get closed and deleted, as they are explicitely off-topic on SO. A comment under the question (which you'll be able to post once you reach 50 reputation) to help the OP is enough. Answering these questions can prevent their automatic deletion and require manual intervention from several hi-rep users. Please help us keep the site clean and useful, flag/vote to close instead.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, thank you the code worked. Im continuing where I left off so my skills are a bit dusty, sorry for that. But may I ask what you mean by "Function sum is never equal to the integer". Did you mean that I cannot use just a function and that I must include its argument as well?

Comment: A function is never equal to an integer. They are objects of two different types that do not have a definition for equality between them. If you _return_ an integer from the function, you need to _call_ the function in any comparison with another integer so you're comparing compatible types -- the integer returned with the integer on the rhs

Answer (score -1):

You are not storing or referencing the result of the sum function. Use one of the two excerpts below to see the result you are looking for.

1. Call function directly into if statement

```
if sum(x, y) == 15:
    print("It is equal to 15")
else:
    print("It is not equal to 15")
```

2. Store function result as variable

```
sumResult = sum(x, y)
if sumResult == 15:
    print("It is equal to 15")
else:
    print("It is not equal to 15")
```